Comparing the asymptotic growth rate.
if I plot both function,
The Problem is, that even after  is no real argument for $f > g$. I Think my math knowledge ends with a function like $g$. Is their a nicer way to show it?

If you take log of both sides you are (essentially) just comparing $x$ to $\log x\times \log (\log x)$.

$$
\frac{(\log{x})^{\log{x}}}{2^x} = \frac{e^{\log{(\log{x})}}}{e^{x\log{2}}} = e^{\log{(\log{x})}-x\log{2}}
$$
Now see that
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \log{(\log{x})}-x\log{2} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} x\left(\frac{\log{(\log{x})}}{x}-\log{2}\right) = -\infty
$$
hence
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(\log{x})^{\log{x}}}{2^x} = 0
$$
